# Are there any performance benefits of making a struct Encodable/Decodable instead of just Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

For an example *struct* `Person` that is to be serialized:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

We could make it conform to the `Encodable`, `Decodable` or `Codable` protocols. I understand that our choice between `Encodable` and `Decodable` is contingent on the use case, (for example if we are hitting an API and do not need to decode a response containing the same type) but we could also make it conform to `Codable` if the struct is to be both used for encoding and decoding.

If we need the struct strictly for encoding **or** decoding, but not both, is it a bad idea **from a performance perspective** to just use a catch-all `Codable` instead of specifying `Encodable`/`Decodable` conformance?

An obvious disadvantage of using `Codable` instead of specifying `Encodable`/`Decodable` is that another programmer may misconstrue the struct as being used for encoding and decoding, when in reality only one of the two is happening. But what if I am strictly interested in performance?

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Try xctests and measure blocks. For example create a struct with Codable conformance and test it on parsing some big json. And then change protocol to Decodable and measure again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one dimension to "performance." It depends on what you mean. For example, adding `Encodable` conformance when it's not needed might increase the size of the binary, which could slow down launch time. Or it might be trivial, since binary size isn't very correlated to launch time (since the file is memory mapped). Or perhaps you mean compile-time performance, where clearly adding auto-generated conformances obviously require some additional complier work, and could in some cases increase the sea of types the type-checker needs to swim through, slowing things down a bit.

But for day-to-day work, it's hard to imagine a case where adding an unnecessary `Encodable` conformance would cause a table view to lag, if that's the kind of performance you mean. Your "another programmer may misconstrue" consideration is much more important.